# Setting the line cap of a CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics

I'm having a really weird error pop up when I try to run one line of code.

I have a subclass of CAShapeLayer, on which I am trying to set the line cap style. I want to use the round cap style, but when I add this code:

```
[self setLineCap: kCGLineCapRound];
```

The build fails and I get this error and warning:

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSString *' is disallowed with ARC
>
> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSString *'

But if I add this:

```
[self setLineCap: kCGLineCapButt];
```

It builds just fine. Why is it breaking on the other line cap type? Is this a problem/bug with Quartz?

---

### Pertinent info.

- iOS SDK 8.1
- Xcode 6.1.1
- Deployment Target iOS 7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CAShapeLayer uses kCALineCap*** which is a defined constant string in the CAShapeLayer.h file, and not a kCGLineCap*** which is part of an enum.